# How to filter a collection based on the attribute of a foreign key object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a collection of Card objects and each Card belongs to a Deck object, and each Deck has a "topic" attribute. How do I make a query for all of the Cards who belong to a deck that has a topic attribute of "casual"

In django it would be,

```
Card.objects.filter(deck__topic="casual")
```

How do I do this in rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use inner join the tables with joins:

```
Card.joins(:deck).where('decks.topic = ?', 'casual')
```

You can use the hash syntax here too:

```
Card.joins(:deck).where(decks: { topic: 'casual' })
```

Note that decks in the where clause is plural.

Comment: Thanks. Is this the same if I want the topic to just include "casual"? Meaning, not match perfectly, just be present in the string somewhere

Comment: No, in that case you want to use regex.     Card.joins(:deck).where('decks.topic REGEXP ?',  'casual')

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make a query for all of the Cards who belong to a deck that has a topic attribute of "casual"

As per the question, your association in `card.rb` looks like:

```
belongs_to :deck
```

You want to fetch all the `cards` i.e you are looking for a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` between `Card` and `Deck` and [`includes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) could do the same thing for you.

[`includes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) also helps you to eager load your association, hence you do not have to execute additional queries when you access `Deck` model attributes from the result of the following join:

```
Card.includes(:deck).where(decks: {topic: 'casual'})
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Tell how this will help ?

Comment: @MaňishYadav edited, please have a look and let me know if it still does not help. thanks :)